# TypeError: 'MoveEvent' object does not support item assignment

Tags: python

Here is the code I have-

```
import mouse
import pickle

#https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard/blob/master/keyboard/mouse.py


with open ('outfile', 'rb') as fp:
    itemlist = pickle.load(fp)


print (type (itemlist[0]))
print (itemlist[:5])

itemlist[0][1] = 5
```

and here is the output:

```
<class 'mouse._mouse_event.MoveEvent'>
[MoveEvent(x=1166, y=56, time=1504454256.95986), MoveEvent(x=1161, y=60, time=1504454256.9678605), MoveEvent(x=1158, y=63, time=1504454256.975861), MoveEvent(x=1150, y=67, time=1504454256.9838612), MoveEvent(x=1146, y=70, time=1504454256.9918618)]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\Move Mouse\mouse mod\mouse_mod_open.py", line 14, in <module>
    itemlist[0][1] = 5
TypeError: 'MoveEvent' object does not support item assignment
```

I am new to python, and I want to try and re-assign values to x and y in the list above.

Answer (score 1):

[Since `MoveEvent` is a `namedtuple`](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard/blob/master/keyboard/_mouse_event.py#L20), you'll need to access the `MoveEvent`'s attributes, and make a new one.

```
# Select the first item of itemlist
old_event = itemlist[0]
# Create the new event
new_event = MoveEvent(x=5, y=1500, time=old_event.time)
```

Change your values as needed.